# dismiss dialog in onWindowFocusChanged() method crashes app

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an Activity like this

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        setItem(R.id.version, R.string.version, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
        setButton(R.id.privacy_policy, R.string.privacy_policy, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPrivacy();
            }
        });
        setButton(R.id.open_source_licenses, R.string.open_source_licenses, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showOpenSourceLicenses();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setItem(int id, int labelRes, int value) {
        setItem(id, labelRes, Integer.valueOf(value).toString());
    }

    private void setItem(int id, int labelRes, String value) {
        View view = findViewById(id);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.value);

        labelView.setText(labelRes);
        valueView.setText(value);
    }

    private void setButton(int id, int labelRes, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        View view = findViewById(id);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.value);
        View navArrow = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_arrow);

        labelView.setText(labelRes);
        valueView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        navArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }

    private void showPrivacy() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showOpenSourceLicenses() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenSourceLicenseActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus && !WorkspaceApplication.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
            new NetworkLostConnectionDialog(this).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the dialog class

```
public class NetworkLostConnectionDialog extends Dialog {

    TextView descriptionView, headerView;
    Context context;

    public NetworkLostConnectionDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = getWindow();
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        //full width dialog and bottom position
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        window.setAttributes(lp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setContentView(R.layout.error_dialog);
        descriptionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_description);
        headerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_header);
        headerView.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_network_error_header));
        descriptionView.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_network_error_description));
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus) {
            if(MyApplication.isNetworkConnected(context)){
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the activity is visible and I pull down the notification menu and turn off wifi, when I go back to activity, the error dialog is shown which is good.
While the error dialog is shown, I turn the wifi back on, the focus comes to dialog and the dismiss() is executed but then it crashes the app.
Here is the stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapplication.workspace, PID: 8020
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findFocus()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3292)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

No idea whats causing this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using onWindowFocusChanged.

Comment: @DougStevenson   The reason why I'm using onWindowFocusChanged in the activity is because onResume is unreliable. While the activity is up, if I pull down the notification menu and turn wifi off then discard it, I'm back to my activity but onResume is not called here. I'm using Nexus6 running 5.1. 
For the dialog, since its not cancelable, I want the dialog to go away if network is restored and it receives focus.

Comment: If you want to know if network connectivity changes, why don't you instead register a broadcast receive that is notified immediately when it's know there is a change?  Right now you're polling for it (not advisable ever to poll when you really want to react automatically), and you're depending on a callback that is inappropriate in this case to do the polling.  Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: @DougStevenson The doc says "As a result, it's good practice to monitor this broadcast only when you've previously suspended updates or downloads in order to resume them." 
My app doesn't require to continuously monitor network state. Only when its up. I had considered broadcast but because of the nature of my app and advice from doc, I decided to go for polling.
Can you think of why the NPE crash would occur or if there is a workaround?

Comment: Then simply register a receiver when your activity is "up" and unregister when not.  You choose the window, and that's common in Android.